# Import jQuery plugin with AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, mmenu

I am using mmenu plugin and I was told that for it to work properly with AngularJS I would need to use a directive. It was already working without a directive by using a timeout function but I know that isn't the right way to do it. So I made one but given that this is my first directive and I just followed what seemed like a similar example I was hoping someone could tell me whether or not this is right or follows best practices.

```
app.directive("mmenu", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).mmenu({
                "slidingSubmenus": false,
                "counters": true,
                extensions: ["multiline"],
                offCanvas: {
                    position: "left",
                    zposition: "front"
                }
            });
        }
}
```

});

Comment: unfortunately $timeout is the only solution

Comment: concept is right...is it working? Note that `element` is already a jQuery object if jQuery.js is included in page before angular ... so `element.mmenu(..` is all that is needed without extra `$()`

Comment: It is, but it was working before I made the directive. I was told that without it I may run into issues with the plugin firing at the wrong time because of the way angular works compared to jQuery. So I had no errors before so it's hard to tell if this actually did anything. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: main reason for doing it in directive is it assures you that element exists when code is run. When you start adding routing, or asynchronous templates  most elements don't exist on page load